# Aggregating Columns/Rows and converting them into valid JSON

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am still pretty new to PostgreSQL and I have trouble with aggregating a few rows and columns which I want to convert to valid JSON.

I have a Table like this:

```
 uid |         name        | count 
-----+--------------------+-------
  15 | latergram          |     1
  15 | wales              |     1
```

I want to concat the columns tag and count to something like '"name": count'.
Afterwards I want to merge the rows with the same uid into one JSON Object. 
The final result should be something like this:

```
 uid |          json_agg          
-----+----------------------------
  15 | ["latergram":1, "wales":1]
```

But best i can manage is this, which is not a valid JSON:

```
 uid |          json_agg          
-----+----------------------------
  15 | ["latergram:1", "wales:1"]
```

This is the Query i used:

```
SELECT foo.uid, json_agg(foo.tag) 
from (
    SELECT uid, (concat(tag || ':' || count)) as tag from test 
) as foo 
group by foo.uid
```

But isn't there a better and especially correct way to achieve that via Postgres?
Help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you limited to using just postgres or can you use another scripting language as well?  If you can use another scripting language, pick one with an ORM (Object Relational Mapping) and a json library (like python/sqlalchemy)

Comment: Well yes, I wanted to achieve that by using only postgtes

Comment: `But isn't there a better way to merge two tables and generate a JSON?` I see only *one* table in your question. Please clarify.

Comment: I have rewritten my post to clarify my problem. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: You should use your application layer to make the conversion to JSON. Unless your database natively supports from JSON conversion function (Postgres doesn't) then you are going to be trying to fit a square peg in a round hole to do you conversion in the DB layer.

Comment: Why not use json column if you want the result in a json?

Comment: `["latergram":1, "wales":1]` is not valid json. You want `[{"latergram":1}, {"wales":1}]` or maybe `{"latergram":1, "wales":1}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you:

```
with cte as(
   SELECT id, string_agg('"' || tag || '":' || count, ',') AS tag
   FROM Table1
   GROUP BY id
)
SELECT c.id, ('[' || c.tag || ']') FROM cte AS c
```

Answer is of the form :

```
   uid |          json_agg          
    -----+----------------------------
    15 | ["latergram":1, "wales":1]
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0e17d/1)**

Comment: Thank you that worked. Seems that i was too focused on using the json functions

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`to_json()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-TABLE) function on yout column `name` to produce valid JSON.
You don't need a subquery or CTE for this:

```
SELECT uid, '[' || string_agg(to_json(name) || ':' || ct, ',') || ']' AS tags
FROM   test
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Using column name `ct` instead of `count` which is a [reserved word in standard SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

[**SQL FIiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1e1a5/1)